# "Aggregate" or "Multicast" sound to multiple wireless devices

Tags: audio, bluetooth-audio

So, here's my scenario: I have a android-powered device (tablet) which where multiple wireless (bluetooth) speakers are registered. Now I want to stream music (using Spotify or Amazon Music) on *ALL* of these speakers at the same time.

Using a device running MacOSX there's a method called [Aggregated Device](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202000) which can supply this. I wasn't able to find something similar on android powered devices.